how to send multiple files and some data in a single response
I'm writing online-library using Vue and Yii2. I need to somehow send books info and related pics.
I tried to send at least pictures but in postman i see that response contains only 1 picture
 public function actionShow()
    {
        $books = Book::find()->all();

        $response = Yii::$app->getResponse();

        foreach ($books as $book) {
            if (file_exists($book->bookPicture || '')) {
                $response->sendFile($book->bookPicture);
            } else {
                $response->sendFile(static::DEFAULT_PICTURE_PATH);
            }
        }
        $response->send();
    }

Is there any way to send at least in separated responses, books info and pics?

HTTP doesn't directly support sending multiple files in one response. Neither does it support sending multiple responses to one request. Technically, you can convert pictures to data urls and send multiple of those but that's  pretty ugly solution. I would simply send links to images in the response that lists books.

Yep, i agree with Michal, I would add that we had the same task and manage that to generate thous docs on the server side and inform the client with the link or page where they can download thous file, it's efficient, and client not waiting while he need thous files.

waiting while download 4-3 files or gen PDF is not fun and it's not that cool 30 secs, deps on the srver config, better to set this to server and get api VUE response when everything is done and inform at that piont.
